# C# - In a method, how can I have 2 parameters that are one?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

In my project I have forms and user controls. I have this important method for changing the mouse cursor.

```
public static void Cursor_Hand(Form frm)
{
      foreach (Control control in frm.Controls)
      {
            if (control.Cursor == Cursors.Hand)
            {
                 control.Cursor = Program.SystemHandCursor;
            }
      }
 }
```

However, it only works if I submit a Form as an argument, I need it to accept Form and Usercontrol.

If possible, I also need both to have the same name, so I don't have to check with IF which argument was sent.

Ignore the wrong syntax, but I wanted something like:

```
public static void Cursor_Hand(Form frm || UserControl frm)
```

Comment: Both classes inherit `ContainerControl` class, you can use it as an argument, or even `Control` (it has `Controls` property)

Comment: change `Form frm` parameter to `Control frm`

Comment: Thanks!, I didn't think it was such a simple solution.

Comment: Note that overloading and generics are also options when types are otherwise unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those types inherit from `Control`:

```
public static void Cursor_Hand(Control frm)
```